# Send transactional email to client in magento before his payment

Tags: email, magento, transactional

Can Magento send an email to client before his payment ? I've been looking for a week, without success!

Thankyou

Comment: Use event/observer logic of Magento to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sending email when new order (regardless of payment) is placed default feature of Magentk

May be you wanna check that this option is not disabled. Go to admin panel to the "System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails -> Order" section.

If that is enabled you have other mail issues:

1. Magento by default use sendmail, which normally goes junk box. But make sure sendmail is installed in hosting, talk to hostig support.
2. The best and recommended is to use SMPT.
   That gaurantee that mail hit inbox.

Comment: Thank you, but stills the problem. Magento says "sent" but it doesn't.